# How does the StackOverflow About page animate itself?

Tags: discussion, jquery, design

How to make a web page like the StackOverflow [About page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about)? I basically want to know what web technology is used to animate the elements as the user scrolls down to that particular place in the page?

I think it uses Jquery, but I haven't found a good place to learn making such a thing?

Can Somebody please explain how this is done, and possibly suggest a place to learn that?

Thanks.

Comment: and now everybody's got a new badge...

Comment: Well javascript :D. It uses similar techniques that are used for parallax scrolling (often this is called that way, even if parallax scrolling is more about the pseudo 3d effect when scrolling in 2d.)

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the source code, you'll see that it's using a lot of `JS` script and `JQUERY`

When the user scroll down the page a code like this one is called :

```js
window.onscroll = function() { 
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset; 
  var Y = 100;
  var parrotW = 138;
  if (scroll < Y){

  }
  if(scroll > Y && scroll <  Y + parrotW){

  }else if (scroll > $(window).height()){

  }
}
```

which will allow you to control CSS Class like that :

```js
$('#parrot').removeClass('slide');    
$('#parrot').removeClass('def');
$('#parrot').addClass('stuck');
$('#parrot').css('bottom', 0);
```

You can take a look at [Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/) which is a very great way to learn code